# What is the differences between the following date assignment statements?

Tags: java

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
```

Assignment statement 1:

```
Date myDate = currentDate;
```

Assignment statement 2:

```
Date myDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime())
```

Comment: Statement 1 creates a new reference to the already-existing currentDate object.  Statement 2 makes a new Date object that contains the same value as currentDate.  Is this a homework assignment or a real-world problem?  We might be able to help more with some context.

Comment: This is a real-world example found out in one of our project. It is being used in setters/getters of POJO. Just want to know if this is the standard or best practice.

Comment: Got it.  It depends on what you need then - if you change `myDate` from statement 1, you'll also change `currentDate` (because both variables are pointing to the same object).  If you change `myDate` from statement 2, `currentDate` will remain the same (because each variable is pointing to a different object).  It's also worth noting that statement 1 uses less memory - creating a new reference is much cheaper than instantiating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date myDate = currentDate;
```

In the first statement there is just one Date object. Both myDate and currentDate are references to this object.

```
Date myDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime())
```

In the second statement, you are creating a new Date object. So myDate and currenDate are pointing to 2 different object.